# Bootstrap JS within angular template files not working

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to have bootstrap js directives (inline tag attributes) work within a angular template file?

All JS libs are correctly loaded, including the js init code for using popovers.
The angular template is correctly loaded using angular router.

All the bootstrap js functions fail to be run/detected in angular templates, is there something i'm doing wrong or is this expected, and is there a way to get it working without changing the html (I looked at angular bootstap ui, but it requires rewriting the html)

Super simplified:
Twig template:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-app="builderApp"><div ng-view></div></div>
```

Angular template:

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="woop woop"></i>
```

Angular JS:

```
var builderApp = angular.module('builderApp', ['ngRoute', 'xeditable']);
    builderApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: template_path + 'root.html',
                controller: 'rootController'
            })
    }]);
    builderApp.controller('rootController', function($scope, directoryFactory) {
        $scope.directory = directoryFactory.getDirectory();
    });
```

Comment: have you included bootstrap module in your application module? Are you not forgetting injecting module?

Comment: Sorry i missed the module creation, but when you say bootstrap module, what is there a bootstrap module you have to inject to have normal bootstrap js work?

Comment: you want to use bootstrap.js directly without going through angular life cycle. This will not work because all your template gets loaded asynchronously and your bootstrap.js don't know anything about it. It is better to use angular wrapper on top of bootstrap like angular UI. Otherwise you can write your own directives which is not advisable because you need to maintain that. :

Comment: Yeah i thought as much, its just a pain angularui doesn't work with html built for bootstrap, ill have to use the angular directive design instead.  But if that's what i must do then I must :) P.S. if no one else can come up with a better answer/solution, put that as an answer and ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would most certainly use the [Angular Bootstrap Directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/top).  I've never seen it done any other way.  This will give you access to the typical bootstrap CSS as well as the interactive functions in the angular bootstrap. I also prefer to use [ui router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="scripts/vendors/ui-router-master/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendors/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>


    var app = angular.module('BuilderApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
            $stateProvider
              .state('login', {
                  url: '/login',
                  title: 'Login',
                  templateUrl:'views/loginView.html',
                  controller: 'loginCtrl'),

              })
              .state('account', {
                  url: '/account',
                  title: 'My Account'


                  views: {
                    'navigation': {
                         templateUrl: 'views/navigationView.html',
                         controller: 'navigationCtrl'
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/contentView.html',
                        controller: 'navigationCtrl'
                    }
                 }            
              })
            .state('account.dashboard', {
                 url:'/dashboard',
                 title: 'Dashboard',
                 views : {
                    'pageContent': {
                        templateUrl:'views/dashboardView.html',
                        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
                }   
             }             
          })
```

And then make sure to inject the router into your controller.

```
app.controller('navigationCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, $state) {
```